# Rails upload xls, save xlsx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel

I'm struggling between some solutions for reading excel files (xls and xlsx) on my rails app. These files (uploaded) are potentially very large, say from 2MB to 200MB.

I already tried roo, spreadsheet and some other minor gems and these are my conclusions:

1. XLSX reading is pretty straightforward. I'm using [Creek](https://github.com/pythonicrubyist/creek) to do this an it takes well care of the job. CPU goes up to 100% sometimes but memory is low which is essential for me.
2. Creek doesn't support xls.
3. XLS reading performs ok with roo. Not too good but still best from all.
4. XLSX reading performs badly with roo. It totally ruins the server's memory and CPU.

I guess you already see my **problem**: Creek, that seems to do the better job, only reads XLSX, not XLS, and roo performs badly with large files generally but specially with xlsx formats.

Thought about uploading a XLS and converting it to XLSX on the server. But didn't find any way to do this fairly quick without compromising as well the server.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Hi! Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue, thanks to this I discovered Creek because roo made my server crash.

Comment: I did a class in the LIB folder so that I would use roo to read xls files and creek to read xlsx files so that when I call this new read class it will be the same way for both file extensions.